# Admin - Error on one particular order view

Tags: admin, orders, error, backend, sales-order

I am getting below error when trying to view one particular order in admin area. I tried to cancel / view but shows error page.

```
There has been an error processing your request

Image file was not found.

Trace:
#0  /app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Helper/Image.php(166): Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Image->setBaseFile(NULL)
#1  /app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/view/items/renderer/default.phtml(38): Mage_Catalog_Helper_Image->init(Object(MDN_AdvancedStock_Model_Catalog_Product), 'thumbnail')
#2  /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/chroot/home/em...')
#3  /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml/defau...')
#4  /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#5  /app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#6  /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#7  /app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Items/Abstract.php(177): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#8  /app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/view/items.phtml(59): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Items_Abstract->getItemHtml(Object(MDN_AdvancedStock_Model_Sales_Order_Item))
#9  /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/chroot/home/em...')
#10  /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml/defau...')
#11  /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#12  /app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#13  /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#14  /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#15  /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('order_items', true)
#16  /app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/View/Tab/Info.php(86): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('order_items')
#17  /app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/view/tab/info.phtml(92): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_View_Tab_Info->getItemsHtml()
#18  /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/chroot/home/em...')
#19  /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml/defau...')
#20  /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#21  /app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#22  /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#23  /app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Tabs.php(303): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#24  /app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/widget/tabs.phtml(38): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Tabs->getTabContent(Object(Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_View_Tab_Info))
#25  /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/chroot/home/em...')
#26  /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml/defau...')
#27  /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#28  /app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#29  /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#30  /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#31  /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
#32  /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#33  /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('left', true)
#34  /app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/page.phtml(58): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('left')
#35  /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/chroot/home/em...')
#36  /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml/defau...')
#37  /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#38  /app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#39  /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#40  /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(555): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#41  /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#42  /app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/OrderController.php(128): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#43  /app/code/community/LucidPath/SalesRep/controllers/Adminhtml/Sales/OrderController.php(56): Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_OrderController->viewAction()
#44  /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): LucidPath_SalesRep_Adminhtml_Sales_OrderController->viewAction()
#45  /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('view')
#46  /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#47  /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#48  /app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#49  /index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#50 {main}
```

All other orders are opening fine except one order.

Anybody who could direct me how to resolve this error?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figure it out, This order contains a product which no longer exists in database. Error "**Image file was not found**" resolved after adding image place holder under:

> System -> Configuration -> Catalog -> Product Image Placeholders and upload Base,
>   Small image and Thumbnail

Once uploaded, view back your order. The product which no longer exists will have this placeholder image.

I hope this will help someone for same issue. :-)